# Loop through multidimensional array and write to file for each parent array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looping through a multidimensional array of field groups and sub fields Using this code:

```
<?php 
$field_groups = acf_get_field_groups();

foreach( $field_groups as $field_group ) { 

    $acf_groups = acf_get_fields_by_id( $field_group['ID'] );

    foreach($acf_groups as $group) {

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($group);
        echo '</pre>';

    }

 }
```

Which gets me this array:

```
array(20) {
  ["group"]=>
  string(6) "button"
      ["sub_fields"]=>
      array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(23) {
         ["name"]=>
         string(11) "button_text"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(19) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(11) "button_link"
      }
   }
}

array(20) {
  ["group"]=>
  string(2) "h1"
     ["sub_fields"]=>
     array(8) {
     [0]=>
     array(23) {
         ["name"]=>
         string(9) "font_size"
     }
     [1]=>
     array(26) {
         ["name"]=>
         string(15) "font_size_units"
     }
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is print out a file with the sub_field values for each of the `$group` arrays ('button' and 'h1' respectively).

So for example, I want to end up with in this case 2 files:

```
button.php
h1.php
```

`button.php` would have:

```
button_text
button_link
```

`h1.php` would have:

```
font_size
font_size_units
```

I can get the two files to print out within that loop however the `h1.php` file includes the `button` `sub_fields` values, so:

```
button_text
button_link
font_size
font_size_units
```

How can I split the files up by the parent array and then print out a file for each group with its respective `sub_fields` values?

Comment: **SOLVED**...see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...needed an additional `grouped` array to group the elements by the key in the nested array, in my case `$sub['label']`.

This isn't pretty or the most elegant but it works.

```
<?php

$field_groups = acf_get_field_groups();

foreach( $field_groups as $field_group ) { 

    $acf_groups = acf_get_fields_by_id( $field_group['ID'] );

    $grouped = array();
    foreach ($acf_groups as $group) {
        $subs = $group['sub_fields'];

        foreach($subs as $sub) {
           $grouped[$group['label']][] = $sub['label'];
        }

        foreach ($grouped as $key => $items) {

            // print by group here.

        }

    }

}
```